# How does WordPress access theme and plugin files through its editor?

Tags: wp-filesystem

I love that WordPress enables you to edit files in the WP back end, but I want to know how it works. How is WordPress able to access and allow you to edit files that are on a server like that? Please let me know if this would be better for a site like stackoverflow.

Comment: What do you mean? It just uses fread/fwrite/etc. You can view the source in wp-admin/theme-editor.php.

Comment: Yeah, the editor is neat until you edit something, trigger a fatal error, the whole site turns white and you can't get back in to fix it.